# Maximum length of **Stranded** Cat5/Cat5e/Cat6 cable

Tags: ethernet, specifications

I know that a network cable run should not be more then 100 meters.    I also understand that solid core cable has better transmission characteristics then stranded cable.

Looking online however, I was surprised that I could not find any statements about the maximum (or even a rule-of-thumb maximum) for stranded cables.    The longest stranded cable length I found for sale was about 66 meters (200 feet), and the longest stranded ethernet my [reputable and knowledgeable] wholesaler seems to sell is 50 meters.  This sort of implies that the maximum length for stranded cable is shorter 100 meters?

Can anyone provide insights/advise the practical limit(s) on stranded copper cable / patch lead length?

Comment: `The stranded copper conductors have small air gaps between the individual copper strands, which causes signal degradation over distance. Those small air gaps don’t transmit signals very well or at all. Although there are on-going debates about this, I personally don’t recommend the use of stranded copper Ethernet cables longer than 75 feet.` https://www.truecable.com/blogs/cable-academy/solid-vs-stranded-ethernet-cable Looks more like a limit in the sense of "most people don't buy such a long stranded cable therefore we don't sell it".

Comment: @Robert That's nonsense or at least borderline - it's not about the air degrading the signal. It's about the air taking up space within the cable. The cross section of a cable directly correlates to the attentuation: the thinner the cable, the higher the attenuation, the shorter the reach. Solid-core cable is AWG 22-23 (Cat. 3 commonly used AWG 24), stranded AWG 26-32.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per IEEE 802.3, the maximum length of a twisted-pair link is 100 m. 90 m of which are required to use solid-core cable, up to 10 m of stranded cable are allowed.

802.3 refers to ISO/IEC 11801 where the cable layout is defined in section *6.2 Layout* (emphasis mine):

> The performance limits for balanced cabling channels are given in 6.4.
> These limits are derived from the component performance limits of
> Clause 9 and 10 assuming **the channel is composed of 90 m of solid
> conductor cable, 10 m of cord(s) and four connections** (see Figure 10).
>
> [image]

Using longer stranded patch cables is certainly possible (I've used up to 30 m) but nowhere guaranteed to work.

Using solid-core cable is highly recommended for static deployment, the most common use case for greater lengths. Solid-core is terminated in patch panels or wall jacks. Do not use modular plugs, the cable breaks rather quickly when moved frequently.

Stranded cable generally has a smaller overall cross section which directly correlates to the cable's attenuation and therefore its reach. Solid core is usually AWG 22 or 23, stranded cable AWG 26 down to 32.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know which 802.3 standard talks about this? Google is failing me.

Comment: @davidgo I've added a reference to IEC 11801.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I see section 7 of iec11801 goes into (too much) depth.